# How to avoid update conflict when updating the same record at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm designing an inventory system with Entity Framework and SQL Server. This app will be used by thousands of users. How do I design an app/database that will allow users to update the same inventory data at the same time? At the moment, for consistency, I use row versioning, but this often causes "Update conflict" errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about Retry Pattern ([here](http://blog.rogatnev.net/2016/07/patterns-retry-vs-circuit-breaker.html) is my post about it). With it you can detect conflicts and make a desicion what to do (rewrite, merge or throw error to user).

Example of usage:

```
var retryCount = 3;
var currentRetry = 0;
using (var context = new DbContext(ConnectionString))
{
    var user = context.Set<User>().First(o => o.Id == 1);
    user.Login = "newuserlogin";
    do
    {
        try
        {
            currentRetry++;
            context.SaveChanges();
            break;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) when (currentRetry <= retryCount)
        {
            //conflict detected
            var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
            //rewrite values from database
            entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(entry.GetDatabaseValues());
        }
    } while (true);
}
```